# syntax for single row MERGE / upsert in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, merge, upsert

I'm trying to do a single row insert/update on a table but all the examples out there are for sets.

Can anyone fix my syntax please:

```
MERGE member_topic ON mt_member = 0 AND mt_topic = 110
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET mt_notes = 'test'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes) VALUES (0, 110, 'test')
```

Resolution per marc_s is to convert the single row to a subquery - which makes me think the MERGE command is not really intended for single row upserts.

```
MERGE member_topic
USING (SELECT 0 mt_member, 110 mt_topic) as source
ON member_topic.mt_member = source.mt_member AND member_topic.mt_topic = source.mt_topic
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET mt_notes = 'test'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes) VALUES (0, 110, 'test');
```

Comment: Hmm, the lines are spaced so close in my browser that some of the underscores are not showing.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Basically, you're on the right track - but you're missing a source from where you want to merge the data - try something like this:

```
MERGE 
   member_topic AS target
USING 
   someOtherTable AS source
ON 
   target.mt_member = source.mt_member 
   AND source.mt_member = 0 
   AND source.mt_topic = 110
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET mt_notes = 'test'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes) VALUES (0, 110, 'test')
;
```

There is no special syntax for a single row MERGE - all you need to do is use a proper clause. With that proper condition in the `ON` clause, you can limit the source to a single row - no problem.

And don't forget the trailing semicolon! No joke - it's important!

See [this blog post](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/using-sql-server-2008s-merge-statement/) for a really good intro to `MERGE`.

Comment: I don't have a someOtherTable. Are you saying I have to simulate one with something like this?

USING (SELECT 0 mt_member, 110 mt_topic) as source

Comment: @Jacob: you have to have a source, yes - a subquery like you mention should be fine - try it!

Comment: For anyone confused by this answer, check out [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216067/what-is-using-in-sql-server-2008-merge-syntax).

Comment: @NateCook: what about my answer is confusing? I'd like to improve it - if possible

Comment: The confusion has to with a misunderstanding of the fundamentals on the part of the readers (myself included). There is nothing wrong with your answer. The other question just expands on the topic for further clarification.

Answer (score 111):

i finally got the Upsert syntax using `MERGE` in SQL Server 2008. Using what Jacob *wanted* to do (an Upsert):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM member_topic WHERE mt_member = 0 AND mt_topic = 110)
BEGIN
    --update existing row
    UPDATE member_topic SET mt_notes = 'test'
    WHERE mt_member = 0
    AND mt_topic = 110
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --insert new row
    INSERT INTO member_topic (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes)
    VALUES (0, 110, 'test')
END
```

The equivalent `MERGE` syntax is:

```
MERGE member_topic
USING ( 
    VALUES (0, 110, 'test')
) AS foo (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes) 
ON member_topic.mt_member = foo.mt_member 
   AND member_topic.mt_topic = foo.mt_topic
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET mt_notes = foo.mt_notes
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes)
   VALUES (foo.mt_member, foo.mt_topic, foo.mt_notes)
; --A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).
```

Comment: In the `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN` clause, why do you insert `VALUES (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes)` and not `VALUES (foo.mt_member, foo.mt_topic, foo.mt_notes)`?

Comment: @SamP Because why not? Is it like SQL Server is going to get the values from someplace *other* than the pseudo-table `foo`? Oh wait...

Comment: Won't the "UPDATE member_topic SET mt_notes = 'test'" line in the non-merge example update _all_ rows in the table? Not what was intended.

Comment: I've found the `IF EXISTS / UPDATE / ELSE / INSERT` pattern to be the source of deadlocks, and incur additional I/O in the best of cases (particularly if the EXISTS / UPDATE has to perform a scan). A better pattern (again in my experience) is to just try and update, and insert if no rows were affected. `UPDATE / IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 / INSERT`.

Comment: The `IF EXISTS` would only hold a lock (and cause a deadlock) if you were running in `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` (i.e. `WITH (HOLDLOCK)`) isolation level. Without it: [MERGE and Upsert both have a race condition](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). With it: [MERGE and Upset both have a deadlock chance.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23467/merge-statement-deadlocking-itself)

Comment: Yes, I wrote that first article. My point was that they both need HOLDLOCK to avoid race conditions (surprised your answer doesn't have a HOLDLOCK) and that when you use UPSERT, you should just to `UPDATE/IF @@ROWCOUNT/INSERT` instead of what people typically do `IF EXISTS / UPDATE / ELSE / INSERT`. The latter has a greater chance of deadlocks.

Comment: Anyway my main reason for commenting is that I continue to recommend to people to stay the heck away from MERGE and use the `UPDATE/IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0/INSERT` pattern, using whatever locking mechanism is more appropriate for their environment.

Comment: ([This one's worth a read too](http://michaeljswart.com/2012/08/be-careful-with-the-merge-statement/).)