# What is USING in SQL Server 2008 MERGE syntax?

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-server-2008-r2, upsert

Jacob asked the perfect question: [*give me the `MERGE` syntax*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479488/syntax-for-single-row-merge-upsert-in-sql-server).

Every answer out there immediately jumps to the most complicated case they can think of; obscuring the syntax with extraneous confusion.

Marc gave [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2479522/12597):

```
MERGE 
   member_topic AS target
USING 
   someOtherTable AS source
ON 
   target.mt_member = source.mt_member 
   AND source.mt_member = 0 
   AND source.mt_topic = 110
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET mt_notes = 'test'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes) VALUES (0, 110, 'test')
;
```

Looking at this answer, i am as confused as Jacob was:

> I don't have a someOtherTable

Marc suggested that `someOtherTable` is a dummy placeholder value - it doesn't matter that you don't have that table.

> i try it, and SQL Server *does* complain
>
> Invalid object name 'someOtherTable'.

That leaves me struggling to understand what the `USING` in `USING foo` is *for* if it's not important (except actually important).

What is `USING` using when it's using *foo* when i use SQL Server 2008 MERGE syntax?

---

### Bonus Question

What is the UPSERT syntax using MERGE:

```
IF (rowExists)
   UPDATE Users SET Firstname='Ian', LastName='Boyd' WHERE Username='iboyd'
ELSE
   INSERT INTO Users (UserGUID, Username, FirstName, LastName, AuthenticationMethod)
   VALUES ('{77410DC5-7A3E-4F1A-82C6-8EFB3068DE66}', 'iboyd', 'Ian', 'Boyd', 'Windows')
```

becomes (exact code i tried):

```
begin transaction

    MERGE 
       Users
    USING 
       foo
    ON  
       Users.UserName = foo.UserName
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Firstname = foo.FirstName, Lastname = foo.LastName
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (UserGUID, Username, FirstName, LastName, AuthenticationMethod)
        VALUES ('{77410DC5-7A3E-4F1A-82C6-8EFB3068DE66}', 'iboyd', 'Ian', 'Boyd', 'Windows')
    ; --A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).

rollback

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'foo'.
```

?

> With a `Users` table that contains the columns:
>
> ```
> UserGUID uniqueidentifier
> Username varchar(50)
> FirstName varchar(50)
> LastName varchar(50)
> AuthenticationMethod varchar(50)
> ```

---

**Update:**

```
USING <table_source>
```

Where `table_source` is:

```
table_or_view_name [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ <tablesample_clause> ] 
    [ WITH ( table_hint [ [ , ]...n ] ) ] 
| rowset_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ] 
    [ ( bulk_column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ] 
| user_defined_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]
| OPENXML <openxml_clause> 
| derived_table [ AS ] table_alias [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ] 
| <joined_table> 
| <pivoted_table> 
| <unpivoted_table>
```

Where `joined_table` is:

> *undefined*

Where `pivoted_table` is:

> *undefined*

Where `unpivoted_table` is:

> *undefined*

Comment: Did you look at the grammar? [`USING <table_source> `](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith Indeed i did. In 14 years of [ [dealing] <with SQL Server> ::= i've never | been | able | to [, ] read { their documentstion }

Comment: [The various undefined parts of the grammar are here BTW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A merge has a table source and a target table. This introduces the source table (which need not be an actual physical table, just a result set).

The grammar is indicated in your question. To merge from another table or view use

```
MERGE 
   Users
USING SomeOtherTableName AS foo /*Alias is optional*/
ON /* ... */
```

Or you can use [`<unpivoted_table>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) for example

```
MERGE 
   Users
USING master..spt_values
UNPIVOT (X FOR Y IN ([high],[low])) AS foo 
ON  
   Users.Username = foo.Y 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET FirstName = foo.Y
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (UserGUID, Username, FirstName, LastName, AuthenticationMethod)
    VALUES (foo.Y, foo.Y, foo.Y, foo.Y, foo.Y);
```

For your bonus question you can use the `VALUES` clause here as part of the `derived_table` option.

```
MERGE Users
USING (VALUES ('{77410DC5-7A3E-4F1A-82C6-8EFB3068DE66}',
      'iboyd',
      'Ian',
      'Boyd',
      'Windows')) AS foo(UserGUID, Username, FirstName, LastName, AuthenticationMethod)
ON Users.UserName = foo.UserName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Firstname = foo.FirstName,
             Lastname = foo.LastName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (UserGUID,
          Username,
          FirstName,
          LastName,
          AuthenticationMethod)
  VALUES (UserGUID,
          Username,
          FirstName,
          LastName,
          AuthenticationMethod);
```

Comment: Well that explain's why the using clause is unimportant - it's **not** unimportant. It's **critically** important. And that explains my confusion with the other answer.

Answer (score 6):

Source table can be anything, such as:

```
MERGE 
   member_topic AS target
USING 
   (SELECT @Variable1, @Variable2, @Variable3) AS source(Col1, Col2, Col3)
ON 
   target.mt_member = source.Col1 
   AND source.Col1 = 0 
   AND source.Col2 = 110
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET mt_notes = 'test'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes) VALUES (0, 110, 'test');
```

Obviously, in the nested source select you can do many more things. Select from a view, a function, a table variable, a CTE even.

As for the bonus question, you answered your own question.

Sometimes,for very large tables, I also use the `ROWLOCK` hint on the target table, to at least try not to lock the entire table in case of updates:

```
MERGE 
   member_topic WITH (ROWLOCK) AS target
```

Related to the bonus question not working, here's a working sample.
I renamed some of the objects, of course.

```
DECLARE @Variable1 AS INT;
SET @Variable1 = 1234;

MERGE dbo.Table1 WITH(ROWLOCK) target
USING(SELECT @Variable1) source(Key)
ON target.[Key] = source.[Key]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    Col1 = @SomeVar1,
    Col2 = @SomeVar2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT 
        ([Key]
        ,[Col1]
        ,[Col2])
    VALUES
        (@Variable1
        ,@SomeVar1
        ,@SomeVar2);
```

Comment: Could also be written as `USING (VALUES (@Variable1, @Variable2, @Variable3))  AS source(Col1, Col2, Col3)`

Comment: My bonus question doesn't work; SQL Server gives the error: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'foo'.`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Not sure about that, but I will try it with the first occasion.

Comment: @IanBoyd: how did you use it? Can you update your question with the full query? Or is it the same?

Comment: Updated question with actual query. SQL Server is correct: i have ***no*** object named `foo`. But then *foo* is just a dummy placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from Martin Smith's answer, you can upsert several explicit value rows at once simply by repeating the brackets, separating with a comma, eg,

```
MERGE Users WITH (HOLDLOCK)
USING (VALUES ('{77410DC5-7A3E-4F1A-82C6-8EFB3068DE66}',
      'iboyd',
      'Ian',
      'Boyd',
      'Windows'),
      ('{00000DC5-7A3E-4F1A-82C6-8EF452D2DE66}',
      'jsmith',
      'John',
      'Smith',
      'ActiveDirectory')) AS foo(UserGUID, Username, FirstName, LastName, AuthenticationMethod)
ON Users.UserName = foo.UserName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Firstname = foo.FirstName,
             Lastname = foo.LastName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (UserGUID,
          Username,
          FirstName,
          LastName,
          AuthenticationMethod)
  VALUES (UserGUID,
          Username,
          FirstName,
          LastName,
          AuthenticationMethod);
```

Tested this on SQL Server 2012. (Would have added this as a comment but too many characters.)

I added a HOLDLOCK having seen [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx), because if you're using MERGE for UPSERT surely the point is locking, the syntax is certainly no clearer. See also Marcel's comment on ROWLOCK for large tables.

There was [another post](http://pratchev.blogspot.ie/2008/03/upsert-and-more-with-merge.html) I found clearer than average, too.