# TSQL Key Constraint Choose Value

Tags: t-sql, key, constraints

I am creating a simple table and adding a key constraint to make sure I have no duplicates when I update the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [TableName](
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE [TableName]
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_row UNIQUE (
[FirstName],[LastName]
);
```

Assume I have a row `Jack Smith 999-999-999` and I am loading `Jack Smith 888-888-888`, the second choice won't be loaded due to key constraint.

Is there a way to specify a table to store new value and delete the old value.

Comment: a table ?  You want to do that with your query (e.g. `UPDATE [TableName] SET [Phone] = '888-888-888' WHERE [FirstName] = 'Jack' AND [LastName] = 'Smith'; `

Comment: The table itself will not do that.  You can do what is called an upsert command.  Search on upsert.  It uses merge.

Comment: @jmugz3 That would work for a simple case, however if my data table has 10000 rows, and I am loading 1000 new rows, where some are unique and some are not ,that wouldn't work

Comment: Answer is only as good as the question.  Not clear where this data is coming from.  Loading 1000 new rows is not very specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax for single row MERGE / upsert in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479488/syntax-for-single-row-merge-upsert-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Paparazzi Thanks for your answer, I will look into `upsert`