# TSQL MERGE with multiple sources

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Originally i tried using an IF/ELSE to accomplish an "UPSERT" and someone suggested I use `MERGE` my issue with `MERGE` is it does not look like I can use two sources.

Here is my Original attempt at an upsert:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(CAST(StudentuserID AS int)) FROM HL_StudentAttendance WHERE StudentUserID=1)>0)
UPDATE HL_StudentAttendance
SET
CID = CAST('[querystring:CID]' AS int),
CalendarEventID = CAST('[querystring:CEID]' AS int),
StudentUserID = CAST('[StudentUserID]' AS int),
Attendance = '[Attendance]'
ELSE
INSERT INTO HL_StudentAttendance
(CID,CalendarEventID,StudentUserID,Attendance)
VALUES
(CAST('[querystring:CID]' AS int), CAST('[querystring:CEID]' AS int), CAST('[StudentsUserID]' AS int),'[Attendance]')
```

Even though the IF statement result is `8` so `8>0` it should run my update it's always running an insert not sure if my if/else logic is missing something.

Here is an attempt with `MERGE`

```
MERGE 
   HL_StudentAttendance AS target
USING 
   HL_CourseRegistrations AS source
ON 
   target.StudentUserID = source.UserID
   AND source.
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET 
   Attendance = '[Attendance]'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (CID, CalendarEventID, StudentUserID, Attendance) VALUES ('[querystring:CID]', '[querystring:CEID]', '[UserID]', '[Attendance]')
;
```

My issue here is that I have data in my table `HL_CourseEvents` that should be used to grab an additional source item being `CalendarEventID` otherwise the `MERGE` works but inserts duplicate entries into my `HL_StudentAttendance` as there is no parameter for `CalendarEventID`

Any suggestions appreciated.

UPDATE

The following query does work, except that it's inserting new records if anything is changed on the attendance field rather than update properly. I suspect because the WHERE clause on my update is not there. I tried adding it getting execution errors

```
MERGE HL_StudentAttendance
USING
(
SELECT cr.CID, ce.CalendarEventID, cr.UserID FROM HL_CourseRegistrations cr
JOIN HL_CalendarEvents ce
ON ce.CID = cr.CID
) tmpTable
ON
HL_StudentAttendance.StudentUserID = tmpTable.UserID
AND HL_StudentAttendance.CalendarEventID = tmpTable.CalendarEventID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET
Attendance = 'Attended Late'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (CID,CalendarEventID,StudentUserID,Attendance) VALUES ('1','1','1','555')
;
```

Results of the query run twice. If i keep running it, it will always insert more instead of updating:

```
ID  CID CalendarEventID StudentUserID Attendance
1   1   1               1             Attended Late
2   1   1               1             Attended Late
3   1   1               1             Attended Late
4   1   1               1             Attended Late
5   1   1               1             Attended Late
6   1   1               1             555
7   1   1               1             555
8   1   1               1             555
9   1   1               1             555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on additional information, try this below. I've hacked together a schema and some data for demonstration purposes only so you'll have to see how your schema compares. However, the two examples at the bottom do what you're asking I believe. The first inserts a new record if it does not exist based on the user id. The second marks that record as "Attended late" if it exists. Note that, for real life you're probably going to need multiple parameters as a user could be signed up for multiple courses, so you'll want to pass in the course or calendar event id as well. Let me know if this gets you started or you need something additional.

```
--
-------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [test].[HL_StudentAttendance]
  (
       [StudentUserID]     INT
       , [CalendarEventID] INT
       , [Attendance]      NVARCHAR(250)
       , [CID]             INT
  );

CREATE TABLE [test].[HL_CourseRegistrations]
  (
       [CID]      INT
       , [UserID] INT
  );

CREATE TABLE [test].[HL_CalendarEvents]
  (
       [CalendarEventID] INT
       , [CID]           INT
  );

go

--
-------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO [test].[HL_CourseRegistrations]
            ([CID]
             , [UserId])
VALUES      (1,1),
            (3,4),
            (4,5);

INSERT INTO [test].[HL_CalendarEvents]
            ([CalendarEventID]
             , [CID])
VALUES      (1,1);

go

--
-------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE [test].[set_attendance] @user INT
AS
    BEGIN
        MERGE INTO [test].[HL_StudentAttendance] AS [target]
        USING (SELECT [cr].[CID]
                      , [ce].[CalendarEventID]
                      , [cr].[UserID]
               FROM   [test].[HL_CourseRegistrations] [cr]
                      JOIN [test].[HL_CalendarEvents] [ce]
                        ON [ce].[CID] = [cr].[CID]) AS [source]
        ON [target].[StudentUserID] = @user
           AND [target].[CalendarEventID] = [source].[CalendarEventID]
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET [Attendance] = 'Attended Late'
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
            INSERT ([CID]
                    , [CalendarEventID]
                    , [StudentUserID]
                    , [Attendance])
            VALUES ('1'
                    , '1'
                    , @user
                    , '555');
    END;

go

--
-- inserts a new record
-------------------------------------------------
EXECUTE [test].[set_attendance]
    @user=12;

SELECT *
FROM   [test].[HL_StudentAttendance];


--
-- marks an existing record as late
-------------------------------------------------
EXECUTE [test].[set_attendance]
    @user=12;

SELECT *
FROM   [test].[HL_StudentAttendance];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The setting of `attendance` is a manual process defined by the user. My issue is that I cannot specify a `UserID` to update in this query

Comment: There is a problem somewhere in the matching of data, when I run the query for the first time it inserts 5 records. Being that i have 5 students that makes sense. I run it a second time and it update 1 of my records and then inserts 5 additional new records where it should be updating instead of inserting at this point.

Comment: Aha! Assuming you're using that in a procedure, you'd use something like shown in my presentation on merge (https://github.com/KELightsey/chamomile/blob/master/presentation/merge.sql) for the procedure [presentation].[merge] using the parameters (using (values(@flower,
              @color)) as source ([flower], [color])). Lunch just arrived in our office. If you still need hints after that I can update.

Comment: I've updated with a results set in case it helps. If you have an example that would be great

Comment: Sorry Katherine i placed my results set in your answer my mistake meant to add it to my question. I cannot undo but you can probably remove it.

Comment: Take a look at my update and let me know if that gets you started in the right direction.