# Can Linq to SQL/Linq to Entities generate a MERGE statement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Looking for a combined INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement, MERGE is exactly what I need, but I can't seem to find if LINQ/SQL supports it (from http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL-Server/SQL-MERGE-35.aspx)

```
-- Merge order items into OrderItems table
MERGE INTO OrderItem As oi
USING @UpdatedItems ui
ON (oi.OrderID = ui.OrderID AND oi.ProductID = ui.ProductID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Quantity = ui.Quantity, UnitCost = ui.UnitCost
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, UnitCost)
    VALUES (@OrderID, ui.ProductID, ui.Quantity, ui.UnitCost)
WHEN SOURCE NOT MATCHED THEN
    DELETE;
```

Comment: If you can't do a MERGE yet, this person shows how to do an "Upsert" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637225/how-would-you-write-an-upsert-for-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of `LINQ to SQL` does not generate a `MERGE` statement. You must create a custom `Upsert` method in code to do an `Upsert`.