# LINQ to SQL CRUD (insert specifically) - inserting multiple items

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I know you can insert new items to your SQL database (LINQ to SQL, code generated by SQLMetal.exe). You can attach new items with the Attach method in your entity table and what not, or you can edit existing records.

Now, let's say, instead of one new entity, you're presented with a lot - some of which may well already exist within the table. There is a primary key, but it's possible there may be some altered records in the collection, so the primary key probably isn't going to be the best method of figuring out what's changed.

Do I have to go through every record in my LINQ table and then compare all of its column data with all of the column data in the entities in the collection in question? This would tell me which ones are new, which ones have had changes, and which ones can be discarded. This just seems like a really long winded way of doing it.

Is there an easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: They call it UPSERT, but in Linq to SQL you have to [roll your own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637225/how-would-you-write-an-upsert-for-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an "UPSERT" is what your after.

It's basically a combined insert/update command for sql, if it exists update it, if not create it.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm

Comment: Don't look at me. I didn't do it.

Comment: @user738383 no worries, whoever did, removed it. Hopefully the link above may give some direction on where to go with your issue.