# LINQ to SQL - Update Database Table from Collection

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

I use database and LINQ to SQL in my Windows Phone application.
I have a database table that stores objects Foo with some ids. There is also an external data source (Json data from server), I can create IEnumerable of Foo from this Json. When I get new data from server I want to "refresh" table - delete all rows with ids that do not exist in new collection, add all new rows and update all existing rows.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can just call delete on the table then commit the entire collection of `IEnumberable<Foo>`. I doubt that's the best way but it's definitely the simplest.

Comment: I do it this way at the moment. The problem is that I need to check differences between 'old' and 'new' records with the same id, it required writing a lot of code by hands. Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: What's the requirement to check the diffs?  Do you need to audit these?  You could MERGE (aka Upsert) the new/updated rows and then delete the ones that don't match in a single transaction.

Comment: 'Upsert' was a correct keyword to google) Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637225/how-would-you-write-an-upsert-for-linq-to-sql